What type of baseboard trim is this? And tips for painting?
Our home was built in the late 90s and has this baseboard and trim throughout. I would like to paint it, but I've discovered it is some type of wood that appears to be covered in a smooth, contact-paper like layer. It looks like wood on the backside.
My question is, would this be something I could peel off in order to paint the existing trim? Is this a particular type of trim? It is on the windowsill trim, baseboards, even the doors! I'm trying to avoid the expense of replacing it all, but I'd love any tips on how to remove the contact paper (if that's what it is) in order to paint the wood (if it's a printable wood?) or if it's even worth it before I get too far in.




Sounds like a cheap wood or fiberboard core with veneer over the surface to make it resemble a more expensive wood. If you're just going to paint it, I would paint over what's there. If you try to remove the veneer, you are going to have to deal with restoring a smooth surface for painting.

Not so much veneer (technically) as thermofoil. So don't peel! Use a primer meant for melamine (usually cabinet doors) and paint away.

Looks like meranti with some sort of glue-on film applied.

This the problem with things that imitate solid wood, like laminated MDF (think most kitchen cabinets), fake oak baseboards, etc.: they look great at the beginning, but don't age well and usually can't be repaired.
You could, in principle, peel off, sand and repaint, but after doing one you'll realize how cheap millwork is at the store. So realistically you have two options:
(1) Do a quick rough sanding to make a surface to paint on, then add primer and a good quality white semi-gloss paint.
Or if the trim is really ugly, peeling apart everywhere, etc.,
(2) Replace the trim with new, then paint. The trim sold at most (all?) lumber yards comes in two grades: paint grade and stain grade. Stain grade is more expensive. It is also made out of pine, so it stains in a very peculiar way, which you might not like, or it might not match your current trim well enough. You'll have to experiment and see if you can live with it. Paint-grade trim is usually finger-jointed, which in my experience is just fine, although a lot of people disagree.
You could try to replace the trim with oak, which will match your current trim, last forever, and will be repairable. But have you seen the price of oak lately? I recently replaced some oak trim and thought the cashier had misplaced the decimal point to the right when I saw the bill.
